# Manifest doesn't work with VF page

Tags: visualforce

I am developing a visualforce page and I would like to use a manifest file with it.

I read [this tutorial](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_container_page.htm) but unfortunately, it doesn't work as I expected.

This is my VF page :

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="Max" manifest="/apex/CacheManifest" docType="html-5.0">

...

</apex:page>
```

And this is my manifest :

```
<apex:page contentType="text/cache-manifest" applyHtmlTag="false" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false">

    NETWORK:
    *

    CACHE:

    #images
    {!URLFOR($Resource.Icone_App)}  
</apex:page>
```

When I run my VF page on my mobile phone then I save the URL on my home page, I can't see the image that I want to use as picture for the shortcut.

Comment: Not sure whether it is the reason or not. It seems you have missed CACHE MANIFEST before NETWORK. Try adding it and see whether it works for you

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work, the logo is not my picture.